# Separating text files

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a text file called `myfile.txt` and copy lines 2,4,6 into a text file called `even.txt` and copy lines 1,3,5 into `odd.txt`. I'm new to programming and this is probably very wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *feven;
  FILE *fodd;
  int lines = 0;

  fp = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
  if (fp ==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  feven = fopen("even.txt","w");
  if (feven ==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fodd = fopen("odd.txt","w");
  if (fodd ==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (fscanf(fp, "%s") != EOF) {
    lines++;
    if (lines%2=0)
    {fprintf(feven,"%s \n");}
    else
    {fprintf(fodd,"%s \n",);}
  }
}//end program
```

Comment: "Any help". Please ask a specific question. If you are having issues with your code as shown then please describe those issues - the input, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour. Also, what did you do to debug the problem on your own before seeking help?

Comment: And suggest you read the man pages for `fscanf` and `fprintf`. You are not giving them the right parameters. What do you expect `fprintf(fodd,"%s \n",)` to do? Where is that call supposed to get the data to write from? Does it even compile?

Comment: If you're trying to read lines, using `fscanf(fp, "%s", ...)` is wrong — it reads words, not lines.  Use `fgets()` to read lines, noting that it keeps the newline in the string it returns.  You probably shouldn't add spaces at the ends of the lines on output, either.  In fact, you should probably use `fputs()` to match the `fgets()` calls.

Comment: I suggest `while (fscanf(fp, "%s") != EOF)` ==> `while (fscanf(fp, "%s") == 1)`. Why `1`? The man page for any of the `scanf` family of functions will tell you that... hint to read the man page. BUT: are you aware that those functions do not read a "line" but stop at the first whitespace? Please use `while(fgets(xxx, sizeof xxx, fp) != NULL)` but as commented, you lack the `xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

You have no room to store the lines, I suggest `fgets` (notice that your code can be simplified using an array of pointers to `FILE`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    FILE *out[2];
    char str[1024];
    int isodd = 1;

    file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    out[0] = fopen("even.txt", "w");
    if (out[0] == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    out[1] = fopen("odd.txt", "w");
    if (out[1] == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, file) != NULL) {
        fprintf(out[isodd], "%s", str);
        isodd = !isodd;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pipped my comment for `fgets`.